# c# - how to overlap spanned labels on tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I've a tebleLayoutPanel in which i want to store bookings. Each row is a room and each column is a date. When i want to insert a booking i insert a label in the arrival cell and i set the span of the label to the departure cell (the label is inserted only in the arrival cell). Is it possible that the departure day match the arrival of another booking: in this case i'd like to overlap the two label but i don't know how to do.
[example of two consecutive bookings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9t2s.png)

Any suggestion?

Comment: A TLP is meant for *layout*, having controls overlap would be a basic layout fail so it won't let you do this.  It just isn't the right control.  Consider the Paint event to draw the grid or use a [Gantt chart control](https://ganttchart.codeplex.com/)

Comment: thank you i'll try the Gantt chart control